# collect data from multiple tables with count and sum

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
SELECT sum(amount) as amount , COUNT(userid) as total FROM table1 WHERE userid='1111'  union all 
SELECT sum(amount) as amount,  COUNT(userid) as total FROM table2 WHERE userid='1111' union all 
SELECT sum(amount) as amount,  COUNT(userid) as total FROM table3 WHERE userid='1111' union all 
SELECT sum(amount) as amount,  COUNT(userid) as total FROM table4 WHERE userid='1111' union all 
SELECT sum(amount) as amount,  COUNT(userid) as total FROM table5 WHERE userid='1111'
```

I found this somewhere but its not working for me .

**Proposed solution:**

The other option is to get data from all tables separately and then display it .

**Question:**

I want to get data from multiple tables with single query. amount will be added and userid will be counted from all tables.

**Additional Notes:**
It should gather all the info about user id = 1111 and save in two varibables.

Userid= 1111 , may not be present in some tables.

Expect out will be like this:

**your total : $total  | and your amount : $amount**

Based on suggestions. here is what i have acheieved so far and how i am trying to display it. it displays nothing without any errors:
If i use single query, then the results are displayed fine.

```
<?php
$sqltotal=mysql_query("SELECT SUM(data.Amount) as Amount ,SUM(data.total) as total 
FROM
   (
     SELECT COALESCE(sum(amount),0) as amount , COALESCE(COUNT(userid)) as total FROM table1  WHERE userid='1111' 
     UNION ALL
     SELECT COALESCE(sum(amount),0) as amount,  COALESCE(COUNT(userid)) as total FROM table2 WHERE userid='1111'
     UNION ALL
     SELECT COALESCE(sum(amount),0) as amount,  COALESCE(COUNT(userid)) as total FROM table3 WHERE userid='1111'
     UNION ALL
     SELECT COALESCE(sum(amount),0) as amount,  COALESCE(COUNT(userid)) as total FROM table4 WHERE userid='1111'
     UNION ALL  
     SELECT COALESCE(sum(amount),0) as amount,  COALESCE(COUNT(userid)) as total FROM table5  WHERE userid='1111'
  ) as data
");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqltotal))  
{
echo "$row[total]";
echo "$row[sum]";
}

//echo "$yourtotal: $row[total]";

?>
```

Comment: is all your tables are inter releated ? with `userID`

Comment: @ameya yes, all share same userid.

Comment: then you should look into `joins`

Comment: $ameya, Can u pls anwer with sample, query with joins

Comment: What's your requirement? Is it to get amount & total for each table for user 1111?

Comment: @sayka, not same id , but all the userid are interrelated.

Comment: @sach , you are right , get all the date in amount and total and display i

Comment: Can you post the error you get?

Comment: In your `echo "$row[total]";
echo "$row[sum]";` this code shouldn't it would be `echo "$row[total]";
echo "$row[amount]";`. I never coded in `PHP` shouldn't the column name should be same. And please try executing query in mysql first make it sure it works ok.

Comment: $coder , changed , but stil no display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the single row for all the tables sum for the column `amount` then just do the Outer select on `UNION`. Now as you mentioned in comment may be some of tables may not contain the `UserID` you need to use the `COALESCE` to make sure that if `null` then get the `0` as selected value.

```
SELECT SUM(COALESCE(data.Amount,0)) as Amount ,SUM(COALESCE(data.total,0)) as total 
FROM
   (
     SELECT COALESCE(sum(amount),0) as amount , COALESCE(COUNT(userid)) as total FROM table1 WHERE userid='1111'  
     UNION ALL
     SELECT COALESCE(sum(amount),0) as amount,  COALESCE(COUNT(userid)) as total FROM table2 WHERE userid='1111' 
     UNION ALL
     SELECT COALESCE(sum(amount),0) as amount,  COALESCE(COUNT(userid)) as total FROM table3 WHERE userid='1111' 
     UNION ALL
     SELECT COALESCE(sum(amount),0) as amount,  COALESCE(COUNT(userid)) as total FROM table4 WHERE userid='1111' 
     UNION ALL  
     SELECT COALESCE(sum(amount),0) as amount,  COALESCE(COUNT(userid)) as total FROM table5 WHERE userid='1111'
  ) as data
```

And if you want to use the join then you need to use the `LEFT JOIN` and also need to do the `SUM` separately for each table and then add that to the main total.

Comment: one of the field in table [amount was named as rate] , that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sum(amount) as amount , COUNT(userid) as total FROM table1
Group By userid
```

Comment: Code-only answers are auto-flagged as low quality and as such are discouraged on stackoverflow. In the future please embellish your answer with details and explain why it is a solution to the question. This helps other users.

Comment: @Sayka: please elaborate on your answer with some explanation showing how it wolves the problem. This will help others who see your code in the future after a search

Comment: You can check my other answers in which how far i've explained to newbies and those in situation. If explanation is required, i would have given.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT sum(table1.amount + table2.amount + table3.amount + table4.amount) as amount, COUNT(table1.userid) + COUNT(table2.userid) + COUNT(table3.userid) + COUNT(table4.userid) as total
FROM table1, table2, table3, table4
WHERE table1.userid='1111' OR table2.userid='1111' OR table3.userid='1111' OR table4.userid='1111'
```